# Extract Keywords from Office Documents with Sharepoint Flow

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

I am trying to implement a document management system using Sharepoint. One major issue is that colleagues cannot find documents in the current setup (local fileserver). They have asked that we have a system that scans uploaded documents and automatically looks for keywords in them and then populates a "Meta" column.

I have had sort of success with OCR on image files, but getting keywords out of office documents (doc, xls etc.) I have had no success until now.

Is there a way to setup a flow to do this task for me?

any help is much aprechiated.

i tried "Get file metadata" and Azure "Text analysis", but it seems to take the raw data of the files (XML I assume) and returns that the document is to large to analyse.

Answer (score 0):

There is something vague about this requirement - how is a keyword defined in a document?

Therefore, first obvious solution would be to assign keywords for each file upon uploading it. You may create a process for this with flow - have tasks, reminders and so on.

Automating this with OCR first means that you need to user OCR that works with MS flow you have only one choice - ElasticOCR. Then, in your flow
- feed the document content to the ElasticOCR action
- keep in mind that OCR is not 100% accurate
- analyze the generated text content according to your keyword definition
- finally write the meta back to the library in the corresponding columns.

Having worked on a similar requirement, we asked uploaders to publish their documents with a short abstract(column from the content type). The assumption is the abstract contains the keywords and is stored in a multi-line column - making it searchable site wide.

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer. for OCR, I found that using the Azure / computer Vision OCR only works with images, not office documents. maybe i´m using it wrong but from the log it seems to fail on .doc or xls. and reg. user generated meta: we have thousands of (old) files that should be parced, thus manual input is not an option. we do want to create a keyword database against which the workflow should match to limit / focus the meta info.

Comment: Hi Nicolas, OK, so let us assume you have a very simple document which contains **Simple generic text info.** Your keyword DB is set to have **generic** as keyword. So the keyword results should be "generic" for this document. For a document of 20 000 words and 100 words big keyword DB that is as much as 2 000 000 iterations. I am not sure what resources you have. On the other hand you may want to have set based approach. Set1 is the document, set2 is the keyword DB. The intersection is "generic". If the intersection score is 100/20000 > 0.005 the keyword is contained at least once.

Comment: hi, i see where you are getting at, but not sure if this is pratical for the end user. but I assume that means at least to your knowledge there is no straight forward / ootb implementation of this in Sharepoint?

Comment: I found this: https://www.anupams.net/azure-text-analytics-tag-sharepoint-documents/, seems to be what i am looking for, but I am not really a coder. I am already lost on where I should put the code he proposes :) :) :)

Comment: that is a very valuable resource but you will need some help from a developer :)